# How to define a rbenv version per executable

Tags: ruby, rbenv

We've got a project where we use capistrano for deployments. Capistrano 3 depends on Ruby 2.2.x to run which is the default version configured with rbenv.

I also use git-up but that depends on ruby 1.9.3, is there a way to make git-up always work with ruby 1.9.3 regardless of where I run it from?

Now I need to constantly switch between ruby versions to run either capitrano or git-up from my project root directory.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to alias the executables with specific ruby executable file like this:

```
alias capistrano="/Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/2.2.3/bin/ruby /path/to/capistrano"
alias gitup="/Users/USER/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3/bin/ruby /path/to/gitup"
```

Then you can call directly `capistrano`/`gitup` with preferred ruby version.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler than Babar's answer, I would make some aliases like this in my zshrc/bashrc

```
alias capistrano="RBENV_VERSION=2.2.3 rbenv exec capistrano"
alias gitup="RBENV_VERSION=1.9.3 rbenv exec gitup"
```

That way we do not need to explicitly set ruby path, it will automatically resolved by rbenv.